# Need help in solving the following efficiently in terms of time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve the problem below for the last two days. I can't think of any solution for it other than brute force. Any kind of hints or references will be appreciated. TIA.

"Given N distinct prime integers i.e `p1`, `p2`,..., `pN` and an interval `[L,R]`. Calculate the number of integers in this interval that are divisible by at least one of the given primes."

**N** is very small (1<=N<=10) and L,R are very big (1<=L<=R<=10^10)

Comment: It' impossible as there are O(n) such numbers (assuming n is the interval length).

Comment: @user4759923 number of given primes(N) will be very less. Can we make use of that somehow ?

Comment: No because there are O(n) numbers in the interval divisible by P1

Comment: Do you have a limit on the magnitude of the primes? How large are your prime numbers compared to L and/or R?

Comment: I think the complexity is O(nprimes * intervalLength). You should at least define what you mean by `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note, it's easier to restrict the problem, and ignore the lower bound (ie: treat L=1). If we can count numbers divisible by the primes <= N for any N, we can also count them on an interval, by subtracting the count of numbers <= L-1 from the count <= R.

Given any number x, the count of numbers <= R divisible by x is floor(R / x).

Now, we can apply the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to get the result. First, I'll show the results by hand for 3 primes p1, p2 and p3, and then give the general result.

The count of numbers <= R divisible by p1, p2 or p3 is:

```
R / p1 + R / p2 + R / p3
- R / (p1p2) - R / (p1p3) - R / (p2p3)
+ R / (p1p2p3)
```

(Here `/` is assumed to be rounding-down integer division).

The general case is as follows:

```
sum((-1)^(|S|+1) * R / prod(S) for S a non-empty subset of {p1, p2, .., pN}).
```

Here `S` ranges over all subsets of your primes, `prod(S)` is the product of the primes in the subset, and the initial term varies between -1 and +1 depending on the size of the subset.

For your problem, N<=10, so there's 1023 non-empty subsets which a small number of things to iterate over.

Here's some example Python code:

```py
from itertools import *

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def prod(ns):
    r = 1
    for n in ns:
        r *= n
    return r

def divs(primes, N):
    r = 0
    for S in powerset(primes):
        if not S: continue
        sign = 1 if len(S) % 2 else -1
        r += sign * (N // prod(S))
    return r

def divs_in_range(primes, L, R):
    return divs(primes, R) - divs(primes, L-1)
```

Note, that the running time of this code is more-or-less only dependent on the number of primes, and not so much on the magnitudes of L and R.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming n is the interval size and N is const.

For each prime p, there should be roughly (R-L) / p numbers in the interval divisible by the prime.

Finding the first number divisible by p in interval: L' = L + (p - L % p).

Now if L' > R, there is none; otherwise there are 1 + floor((R-L') / p).

Example: 3, [10, 20]:

L' = 10 + 3 - 10 % 3 = 12.

Numbers divisible by 3 in the interval: 1 + floor((20 - 12) / 3) = 3

Note: So far we haven't used the fact that p1..pN are primes.

Remaining problem seems to be: How to avoid counting a number divisible by multiple primes multiple times? Example: Assuming we have 3,5 and [10, 20], we need to avoid counting 15 twice...

Maybe we can just count divisibility by (p1*p2) etc. using the counting algorithm above, and reduce the total accordingly? If N ist const, this should still be const time. Because p1...pN are prime, all their products need to be different (as any number can't have more than one prime factorizations).

Comment: Note that for numbers divisible by multiple primes, you have to be a bit more careful. You actually need to look at all possible combinations of p1…pN and add or subtract them properly. This is called the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). So you do have some actual complexity there since you need to count the numbers for the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the prime numbers. So assuming that the calculation for a single prime is constant, you still have a complexity of O(2^N).

Comment: Well... O(2^c) = O(1)

Comment: Assuming `N` is a constant, sure, but with OP’s problem description, it sounds more like an input.